# term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, opencv, image-processing, c++-cli

Please have a look at the following OpenCV code

```
    Mat *curent;
    current = new Mat();
    cv::Rect bRect = cv::boundingRect(Mat(*points).reshape(2));

    Mat roi = *current(bRect);
```

Here, I am trying to get a ROI to the Mat called `roi`. But whenever I try to get execute the last line of the above code I get the error `term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments`. I have followed the same technique of getting an ROI without pointers number of times before in C++ and they worked. I guess the issue is with pointer `current` ? `current` must be a pointer because local variable slowed the application in an unbelievable way.

So, how can I solve this issue and get the ROI ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please, throw out those pointers!

you're going to wreck havoc on the internal Mat refcounts, produce undefined behaviour and memleaks

"local variable slowed the application in an unbelievable way."

really, you think, copying a 58 byte struct is the reason ? i just don't believe you.

well i'll give you a hint, anyway -  the ( ) operator has a higher precedence than the * operator.

Comment: This is a real time application. That is why re creating variables make things worst. I have tested it. Anyway, I did not get your hint. Can you please describe/provide example please?

Comment: Mat roi = (*current)(bRect);